# VSCode Vim plugin folding ctrl+k ctrl+<number>

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscodevim

I'm using VSCode with Vim extension enabled.

By default, VSCode `Ctrl+K Ctrl+number` would fold the code of the entire file to the indent level set by the number.

[image: VSCode default folding commands]

This is ***EXTREMELY*** useful for me, and I use it all the time.

The problem is: with the Vim extension enabled, those commands doesn't work anymore.

This extension also doesn't allow (as far as I know) to change configurations such as ":set foldmethod=indent".

Are there any workarounds?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ORIGINAL SOLUTION:

The most simple solution I found was to ***disable*** `Vim: Use Ctrl Keys` at

```
Settings > Extensions > Vim > Vim: Use Ctrl Keys
```

(you can type "vim ctrl" in the search bar to find it faster).

[image: VSCode Settings > Vim: Use Ctrl Keys]

You can also add `"vim.useCtrlKeys": false,` directly in your settings.json.

It's good enough for me, but be aware that it can mess up your Vim commands, as it will not use any Ctrl commands anymore.

---

***MUCH BETTER SOLUTION:***

Just put this in settings.json!

```
"vim.handleKeys": {
    "<C-k>": false
},
```